# Gzip a website with inline PHP code

Tags: php, gzip

According to [this article](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/)

it's enough to add this at the beggining of the code

```
<?php if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); else ob_start(); ?>
```

I tried, but the loading time has increased more than 5 seconds (+100% time)

Is this not recomended? shall I try somehow else?

Comment: Did the loading time really increase, or is it just that now everything is delivered only when the whole script has run, whereas until now, data started to trickle in bit by bit? Because that's by design, it's in the nature of compressing output this way

Comment: @Pekka Isn't that rather in the nature of output buffer? :)

Comment: @Petr exactly, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code example given in the linked article is somehow misleading (although that's not answering your speed issue upfront).

The `ob_gzhandler` callback works transparently, so it's only in effect when the browser actually supports some kind of compression (not only `gzip` as in your manual check), so the manual check is not necessary. Instead you can just write:

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
```

Which is

```
ob_start();
```

in case the browser does not support compression. Alternatively you can set the corresponding ini value. See [`ob_start`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [`ob_gzhandler`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php).

If you would like to measure the speed differences, please only compare `ob_start()` (no compression) against `ob_start("ob_gzhandler")` (compression) and not buffering against not buffering.

Then keep in mind that the gzhandler operates on chunks so it can only create output if there is a certain amount of data buffered. This can be configured with the ini setting, but not the callback function IIRC. See [`zlib.output_compression`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php#ini.zlib.output-compression).

Answer (score 0):

Compressing takes some time and resources from server, but transfer is faster. It depends.

If you have fast server, it should be fast. It depends on

- Network connection
- Server resources (such as proccessor)

However, I don't think this is necessary, I think that if you have gzip compression plugin on your server, it's gziping automatically.

Try [this](http://www.whatsmyip.org/http_compression/) test without your code and then with

Comment: interesting: http://www.whatsmyip.org/http_compression/?url=aHR0cDovL2tlZXB5b3VybGlua3MuY29t so do you think i shouldn't do anything?

Answer (score 0):

Just use following code .

```
<?php 
if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) {
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
} else{
 ob_start(); 
?>
```