# How to print out whether the current web page is compressed?

Tags: php, gzip

I am using a .htaccess file to compress my .php , .css and .js files. What I want to do is to echo out in my footer is GZIP enabled or not.

For example if its not enabled by the server to echo out GZIP is not enabled or of it is to echo out GZIP is enabled.

I've looked around the net and couldn't find a php script doing that. I thought I could make it work with ini_get() but obviously unsuccessfully.

Can someone give me a tip?

Thanks :)

Comment: What directive have you put in your `.htaccess` to enable it? In short, what are you checking for? You could show whether PHP's internal `ob_gzhandler` is enabled with `ini_get()`, but if you are using an Apache module to do the compression, this could be more difficult, if it's possible at all...

Answer (score 1):

I have problems to understand your question. If you want to find out if the gzip encoding of your server and php configuration works, you need to check that with an additional program sending requests to the URLs in question and check if gzip is used. One such tool is [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) on the commandline:

```
$ curl --compress --raw -i URL
```

Example:

```
  $ curl --compress -I https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029168/show-is-my-gzip-enabled-on-my-webpage

  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Cache-Control: public, max-age=18
  Content-Length: 8683
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
*****************************
* Content-Encoding: deflate *
*****************************
  Expires: Sun, 06 Nov 2011 18:21:05 GMT
  Last-Modified: Sun, 06 Nov 2011 18:20:05 GMT
  Vary: *
  Date: Sun, 06 Nov 2011 18:20:46 GMT
```

See the line I highlighted:

```
Content-Encoding: deflate
```

it signals that something gzip is active. See [RFC2616 - HTTP/1.1 14.11 Content-Encoding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.11) for the full meaning of this line.

More information is available in a related question/answer: [PHP Output buffering, Content Encoding Error caused by ob_gzhandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6402806/367456#6403260).

If that's not your issue maybe [Gzip a website with inline PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7158595/367456) is helpful.

Comment: Hey that's a nice idea... although the result of the check should probably be cached as you don't want to request a "remote" file for every page load - and obviously, don't request "yourself" (the same script) or you will end up in an endless loop...

Comment: That curl command needs to be run manually, not automatically, in the shell. It would make no sense to run this from within PHP.

Comment: I've worked it out following your method with curl, thanks a lot! :)